Does JobRnr has support for postgress (using pg adpdater for google spanner)?
Getting error while starting up the application, currently using JobRunr 7.2.2 version but I also tried downgrading it and each time end-up getting different error.
I also tried manually generating script and then applying it using liquibase, but due to Google spanner incompatibility nothing worked out.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Type  is not supported.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:177) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DatabaseCreator.updateMigrationsTable(DatabaseCreator.java:152) ~[jobrunr-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DatabaseCreator.runMigration(DatabaseCreator.java:125) ~[jobrunr-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
... 47 common frames omitted

Update 1:
I generated the script and made required changes, but it seems job runr is running some script which is not supported.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Statements with
ROW MARK clauses are not supported - Statement: 'select jobAsJson from
jobrunr_jobs where state = $1 ORDER BY updatedAt ASC LIMIT $2 FOR
UPDATE SKIP LOCKED'   at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar:42.6.2]   at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2

Update 2:
Deployed Postgress as sidecar in k8s and the configured the Storage object but got the error.
Bean configuration:

@Bean
@Profile("!dev")
public StorageProvider postgresStorageProvider() {
logger.info("Configuring PostgresStorageProvider");
DataSource ds = dataSource();
if (ds == null) {
logger.error("DataSource is null!");
throw new IllegalArgumentException("DataSource cannot be null");
}
return new PostgresStorageProvider(ds);
}
public DataSource dataSource() {
    logger.info("Configuring DataSource");
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/yourdatabase");
    dataSource.setUsername("myuser");


    dataSource.setPassword("mypassword");
    return dataSource;
}


2024-07-30T00:48:33.575+05:30 ERROR 16574 --- [fx-checkout-service] [ool-17-thread-2] [                                                 ] org.jobrunr.server.BackgroundJobServer   : Unexpected exception running CheckIfAllJobsExistTask

org.jobrunr.JobRunrException: JobRunr encountered a problematic exception. Please create a bug report (if possible, provide the code to reproduce this and the stacktrace)
at org.jobrunr.JobRunrException.shouldNotHappenException(JobRunrException.java:43) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.server.tasks.CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.run(CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.java:45) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233) ~[na:na]
at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.RecurringJobTable.(RecurringJobTable.java:24) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DefaultSqlStorageProvider.recurringJobTable(DefaultSqlStorageProvider.java:386) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DefaultSqlStorageProvider.getRecurringJobs(DefaultSqlStorageProvider.java:322) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.storage.ThreadSafeStorageProvider.getRecurringJobs(ThreadSafeStorageProvider.java:173) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.server.tasks.CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.getDistinctRecurringJobSignaturesThatDoNotExistAnymore(CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.java:50) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
at org.jobrunr.server.tasks.CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.run(CheckIfAllJobsExistTask.java:31) ~[jobrunr-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
... 6 common frames omitted

I don't know why you mention you're using JobRunr v7.2.2 as the first stacktrace shows JobRunr v7.0.0 and the second stacktrace v6.3.4.
JobRunr surely supports postgres, it is the most used database in combination with JobRunr.
